# Set Tag in Release Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, release

I have a problem in CI/CD.
Set automatized add tag in release pipeline, for intern step(task or PowerShell) in release

example in powershell in build pipe:

```
Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$(ENVIRONMENT)
```

add field manually:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logging command you are using is to add build tags, it's not applied to release. See [Logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#addbuildtag-add-a-tag-to-the-build) for details.

We can add release tags by add a PowerShell task to run a script calling the REST API, below sample for your reference:

1. Grant the `Release Manage` permission for the account "`Artifacts Build Service (xxx)`"

Go to **Pipelines** > **Release** > **Security** > Search for "`Artifacts Build Service (xxx)`" account, and set the **Manage Releases** permission to **Allow**
[image]

2. Edit the release pipeline, enable the option "`Allow scripts to access the OAuth token`" in **Agent Job**.
   [image]
3. Add a PowerShell task at the end of the pipeline and run the following script to call the REST API to add release tags.

```
Write-Host "TAG:" $(ENVIRONMENT)   
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI)Artifacts/_apis/Release/releases/$($env:RELEASE_RELEASEID)/tags/$(ENVIRONMENT)?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PATCH -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}`
```

[image]

4. Create a release, refresh the page after the release completed, check the result.
   [image]

[image]

Comment: thank you, but would Azure devops have another solution? because the Rest API is an extreme process to set the tag at release.

Comment: @Ivo Paulo Puehler No other ways if you want to do that automatically.  And it's simple to follow the steps in a release pipeline.